# swiper как расположить слайдер слева

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Несколько месяцев изучаю WEB. Сделал страницу со слайдером swiper.
Не понятно, как расположить слайдер слева и расположить пагинацию близко к низу картинки. Если можно ответ подробный с описанием.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  grabCursor: true,
  cubeEffect: {
    shadow: true,
    slideShadows: true,
    shadowOffset: 50,
    shadowScale: 0.3,
    centerSlidesBounds: true,
  },

  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,


  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 1500px;
  /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}

.swiper-container {
  //width: 550px;
  //height: 270px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 550px;
  height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201309/119067.jpg" alt></a>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201408/148243.jpg" alt></a>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201111/50599.jpg" alt></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'cube',
  grabCursor: true,
  cubeEffect: {
    shadow: true,
    slideShadows: true,
    shadowOffset: 50,
    shadowScale: 0.3,
    centerSlidesBounds: true,
  },

  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,


  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 1500px;
  /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}

.main__slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.main__slider-inner {
  max-width: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main__slider .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
  bottom: -50px;
}

.swiper-container {
  //width: 550px;
  //height: 270px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 550px;
  height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__slider">
    <div class="main__slider-inner">
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201309/119067.jpg" alt></a>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201408/148243.jpg" alt></a>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201111/50599.jpg" alt></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает, только нужно слева а не  справа.

Comment: Добавил в стиль ".main__slider-inner" строку: left: -430px;. Стало, как нужно слайдер слева. Не могли ли Вы дать пояснения зачем нужно было создавать классы:main__slider, main__slider-inner? Мне это нужно, чтобы понять, как все работает.

Comment: @inquirer 1) ```main__slider``` - обертка, непосредственно для позиционирования блока.  2) ```main__slider`-inner``` - класс, чтобы задать размер слайдеру, в данном случае ```550px``` + добавляем ```position: relative```, т.к кнопки управления слайдера позиционируются c помощью ```position: absolute```

Comment: Тогда может быть классы:swiper-container, swiper-wrapper не нужны? Опыта в данном направлении мало, поэтому трудно понять. Я читал на самом сайте swiper, что в начале идет основной контейнер, затем оболочка  и потом сами слайды(всего три класса).

Comment: @soledar10 - нужны, это классы для слайдера